# how to iterate (loop) over key, value in terraform templates?

Tags: terraform

#### Situation:

I have an example template file (`example.yml.tftpl`):

```
secrets:
  %{ for env, key in map_of_params }
  - name: "${env}"
    valueFrom: "${key}"
  %{ endfor ~}
```

And terraform code:

```
terraform {
  required_version = "~> 1.2"

  backend "local" {
    path = "./terraform.tfstate"
  }
}

data "template_file" "example" {

  template = "${file("${path.module}/example.yml.tftpl")}"

  vars = {
#    1. set map_of_params as map
# -> map_of_params = {
#      "aaa_env" = "aaa_key"
#      "bbb_env" = "bbb_key"
#    }
#    2. set map_of_params as string
# -> map_of_params = "string"
#    3. map-like string
# -> map_of_params = "{\"aaa\" = \"bbb\", \"ccc\" = \"ddd\"}"
  }
}

output "rendered" {
  value = data.template_file.example.rendered
}
```

[Here](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/templatefile#maps) is example how to iterate over map key / value:

```
%{ for config_key, config_value in config }
set ${config_key} = ${config_value}
%{ endfor ~}
```

```
> templatefile(
               "${path.module}/config.tftpl",
               {
                 config = {
                   "x"   = "y"
                   "foo" = "bar"
                   "key" = "value"
                 }
               }
              )
set foo = bar
set key = value
set x = y
```

I can't see difference between my code and official example except the official example is a `templatefile` function instead of `template_file` data source.

#### Problem:

If I using first case when `map_of_params` is real map, this error appears:

```
╷
│ Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│
│   on main.tf line 13, in data "template_file" "example":
│   13:   vars = {
│   14:     map_of_params = {
│   15:       "aaa_env" = "aaa_key"
│   16:       "bbb_env" = "bbb_key"
│   17:     }
│   18:   }
│
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "vars": element "map_of_params": string required.
╵
```

When I trying to set `map_of_params` as string, it shows me:

```
╷
│ Error: failed to render : <template_file>:2,22-35: Iteration over non-iterable value; A value of type string cannot be used as the collection in a 'for' expression.
│
│   with data.template_file.example,
│   on main.tf line 9, in data "template_file" "example":
│    9: data "template_file" "example" {
│
╵
```

<s>What the F..?</s>  I mean how to set `map_of_params` as map and prevent `string required` error simultaneously ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't see difference between my code and official example except the official example is a templatefile function instead of template_file data source.

The difference is that `template_file` **does not support** maps nor lists as arguments. It only accepts strings, thus you get error `string required`.

Only `templatefile` supports maps so you have to use `templatefile` if you want to use your `map_of_params` which is a **map**, not string.

Rendered value may be saved in `locals` instead of `template_file` data source:

```
terraform {
  required_version = "~> 1.2"

  backend "local" {
    path = "./terraform.tfstate"
  }
}

locals {
  template = templatefile("${path.module}/example.yml.tftpl", {
    map_of_params = {
      "aaa_env" = "aaa_key"
      "bbb_env" = "bbb_key"
    }
  })
}

output "rendered" {
  value = local.template
}
```

Output:

```
Outputs:

rendered = <<EOT
secrets:

  - name: "aaa_env"
    valueFrom: "aaa_key"

  - name: "bbb_env"
    valueFrom: "bbb_key"

EOT
```

Comment: Thank you for answer Master of Terraform, I was waiting for you :-) Yeah, that is the most obvious explanation. Actually I already updated my code couple minutes ago and it is works with function. So is this problem some kind of bug or TODO? Why it doesn't support `map` inside terraform block but support `%{ for }` syntax inside template? Or `template_file` is just a legacy feature that is not updated?

Comment: @rzlvmp `template_file` is not recommended to be used as explained on its docs. I guess its simply not updated anymore.

Comment: I little bit updated answer to complete it

Comment: Indeed, `template_file` was originally written for Terraform v0.11 and earlier which didn't yet have the `templatefile` function built-in. From Terraform v0.12 and later `templatefile` is the replacement. There was one final update to `template_file` to support the Terraform v0.12-style template language, but it cannot support any type other than string as input because it needs to remain protocol-compatible with Terraform v0.11, which doesn't support that.

Comment: @MartinAtkins Is it verified info? probably it should be an answer instead of comment